# Distance contraction in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Say that a comet explodes over Jupiter. And we were watching this from earth. There should be a time lag in reality as the light takes finite time to reach us.

Now if we supposed an inertial frame with some speed approaching that of light, would there be that moment where the distance between the Earth and Jupiter become zero? And the explosion occurs in both their skies at the same time (with respect to the frame)

Say that we have two events: event 1 is when the comet hits jupiter, and event 2 is when the flash is seen on earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the distance will become smaller as the speed gets closer to the speed of light, but because it can never reach it, it will never be zero.

Comment: OK. So does that mean the time difference measured in this moving inertial frame be very close to zero?

Comment: yes, it does, because the speed of light remains the same and the distance for that observer is shorter